# CNN-LSTM proprocessing Even if you proceed with interpolation, etc., the Nan value does not disappear

Tags: python, deep-learning, pytorch, lstm

```
# 빈 데이터프레임 생성 함수 정의
def create_empty_df(index_list, columns):
    return pd.DataFrame(index=index_list, columns=columns)

# 센서 데이터 처리 함수 정의
def process_sensor_data(label_data, cols, interpolation_method='linear'):
    # 최소 시간값 구하기
    base = np.min(label_data['Htime'])
    # 최소 시간부터 최대 시간까지 20밀리초 간격으로 시간 리스트 생성
    datetime_list = pd.date_range(np.min(label_data['Htime']), np.max(label_data['Htime']), freq='20L')
    # 빈 데이터프레임 생성
    test_df = create_empty_df(datetime_list, [cols])

    # 값이 있는 경우 해당 값을 채우고, 없는 경우 NaN으로 채움
    for tdf in range(len(test_df)):
        value = label_data[label_data['Htime'] == test_df.index[tdf]][cols]
        test_df.iloc[tdf, 0] = value.iloc[0] if not value.empty else np.nan

    # 센서 데이터가 포함된 컬럼에 대한 처리
    if cols in ['Gyro_x', 'Gyro_y', 'Gyro_z', 'Acc_x', 'Acc_y', 'Acc_z']:
        test_df[cols] = test_df[cols].astype(float)
        
        # NaN 값 채우기: forward fill (앞 방향으로 채우기)
        test_df.fillna(method='ffill', inplace=True)
        # NaN 값 채우기: backward fill (뒷 방향으로 채우기)
        test_df.fillna(method='bfill', inplace=True)
        
        # NaN 값을 보간법으로 채우기 (기본값은 선형 보간법)
        test_df.interpolate(method=interpolation_method, limit_direction='both', inplace=True)

    return test_df

# 시프트 및 필터링 함수 정의
def shift_and_filter(test_df, cols):
    # 데이터를 이동시키기 위한 리스트 생성
    shifted_dfs = [test_df[cols].shift(x) for x in range(-1, -150, -1)]
    # 이동된 데이터를 하나의 데이터프레임으로 합치기
    shifted_df = pd.concat(shifted_dfs, axis=1)
    shifted_df.columns = ['Shift_' + str(x) for x in range(-1, -150, -1)]
    test_df = pd.concat([test_df, shifted_df], axis=1)

    # 인덱스를 재설정하고 원하는 데이터만 선택하기
    test_df.reset_index(drop=True, inplace=True)
    test_df = test_df.iloc[test_df.index % 75 == 0]
    
    # NaN 값을 보간법으로 채우기 (기본값은 선형 보간법)
    test_df.interpolate(method='linear', limit_direction='both', inplace=True)
    
    # NaN 값을 포함하는 행 제거
    test_df = test_df.dropna(how='any', axis=0)

    return test_df


# 센서 데이터 및 메타데이터를 저장하기 위한 리스트 생성
for col in range(len(data.columns)):
    if 2 <= col <= 7:
        col_name = data.columns[col]
        globals()['{}_list'.format(col_name)] = []
    elif col == 8:
        col_name = data.columns[col]
        globals()['{}_list'.format(col_name)] = []

globals()['behavior_list'] = []


count = 0

# 각 행동 데이터에 대해 처리
for i in range(len(h_data)):
    
    count += 1
    if (count == 30) :
        break
        
    # 해당 시간 범위와 '이름' 컬럼 값이 일치하는 label_data 추출
    label_data = data[(data['Htime'] >= h_data['시작시간'].iloc[i]) & (data['Htime'] <= h_data['종료시간'].iloc[i])]
    label_data = label_data[label_data['Pname'] == h_data['이름'].iloc[i]]
    # h_data의 'total_behavior' 값을 label_data의 'behavior' 컬럼에 할당
    label_data['behavior'] = h_data['total_behavior'].iloc[i]
    
    if len(label_data) == 0:
        continue

    test_df_len = 0

    # label_data가 비어있지 않은 경우, 다음 작업을 수행
    for cols in label_data.columns:
        # 'Cnt', 'Htime', 'Pname', 'behavior' 컬럼은 건너뛴다
        if cols == 'Cnt' or cols == 'Htime' or cols == 'Pname' or cols == 'behavior':
            continue

        # 센서 데이터 처리
        test_df = process_sensor_data(label_data, cols)

        # 시프트 연산 및 필터링
        test_df = shift_and_filter(test_df, cols)

        # test_df의 길이를 계산하고, 해당 길이만큼 각 리스트에 값을 추가
        test_df_len = len(test_df)
        test_df.apply(lambda x: globals()["{}_list".format(cols)].append(list(x)), axis=1)

    # 각 리스트에 행동과 이름 정보 추가
    for l in range(test_df_len):
        globals()['behavior_list'].append(label_data['behavior'].iloc[0])
        globals()['Pname_list'].append(label_data['Pname'].iloc[0])
```

some in my code the process is structured like this

1. Create an empty dataframe: The create_empty_df function creates an empty dataframe using the given index list and column names.
2. Process sensor data: The process_sensor_data function creates a time index for each sensor data column and handles NaN values. This is done using linear interpolation.
3. Shifting and Filtering: The shift_and_filter function performs a shift operation on the given dataframe and removes rows containing NaN values. This task is used to process time series data.
4. Save data: This task runs over the entire dataset and creates a list to store each sensor data and metadata.
5. Processing each behavioral data: For a given range of behavioral data, we process the sensor data, perform shift operations and filtering, and then add behavioral and name information to each list.

However, if you try to count the number of Nan values, can you figure out what the problem is because the Nan values are still there?

Later, even if `train_test_split` was executed, `train_test_split` was not executed because the number did not match.

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Please remember that Stack Overflow is not your favourite Python forum, but rather a question and answer site for all programming related questions. Thus, always include the tag of the language you are programming in, that way other users familiar with that language can more easily find your question. Take the [tour] and read up on [ask] to get more information on how this site works, then [edit] the question with the relevant tags.

Comment: Also do note that [posts on Stack Overflow have to be in English](/help/non-english-questions). Though this is not a fixed requirement for comments within the code, it would help a lot if you'd translate those, given the amount of comments within your code. Comments in any language but English can be considered noise, given that English is the only common language (and only language acceptable for plain text) on Stack Overflow.